# Mix c++ with objective-c pointers, structs

Tags: c++, objective-c, pointers, struct

I struggle a bit with integrating some c++ into my objective-c code in xcode.
I first wrote a c++ program which plays some audio and it worked fine. It consists of some functions and a struct. Before I tried to integrate it in my objective-c code I did something like this:

```
typedef struct MyPlayer {

//some declarations...

} MyPlayer;
void createInput(MyPlayer *player);
//some other functions...
```

and in the main of the c++ file:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
MyPlayer player = {0};

// create it
createInput(&player);
}
```

which worked perfectly.

Now I thought, okay lets bring it over into objective-c

added player into the header file of the objective-c code..

and did something like this:

```
 self.player = {0}; //does not compile, commented it out to test
 createInput(self.player);
```

and with = {0} commented out it compiles, but crashes when it tries to get into createInput.
how can I use the pointers or fill the struct with {0} when I have such a objective-c + c++ project?

Why get it into objective-c? Because my interface is built in objective-c/cocoa

Thanks!
Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in the Objective-C case, the player structure isn't a local variable - it has assumedly been declared as a property. When you assign a value using `self.player`, you are essentially calling the property setter method `[self setPlayer:{0}]` which doesn't make any sense.

Looking at how you're using the code, I'm assuming *player* is actually declared as a pointer to a *MyPlayer* struct, so you would need to allocate memory for it. If you use `calloc` for that you can create the structure and initialise it to zero at the same time.

Something like this:

```
self.player = calloc(1, sizeof(MyPlayer));
```

This allocates the memory, sets the contents to zero, and calls the property setter to assign that memory to the *player* property.

If I've got that wrong, it would help if you showed how *player* has been declared in the Objective-C code.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how exactly you are declaring the structure object.
but the following code is working fine

```
typedef struct myStruct{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
}myStruct;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myStruct abc = {0}; //works fine

    // myStruct abc;  
    //self.abc = {0}; //error  

    NSLog(@"%d %d %d",abc.a,abc.b,abc.c);
}
```